# How can I round seconds to 2 places upon using R package lubridate's seconds_to_period function?

Tags: r, datetime, rounding, lubridate, datetime-conversion

I converted seconds to `DD:HH:MM:SS` format using the R package Lubridate's function `seconds_to_period`. Now I have a huge list of times which look like this -> `2d 7H 1M 5.31500000000233S`. I need to round off the seconds to 2 decimal places.
I tried using `round_date` and `ymd_hms` but I receive this `error in as.POSIXct.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied`. I tried if I could access the seconds separately and write a function to change them but could not. How can I solve this?

Attached a duration.RData file and durdata.R file for reference data. Both the files have the same data but one is using dput() and other using save(). Link : [link to files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uIF3prma5jrS9BhoTcct-S1h4NXVqcpM)

Comment: @RonakShah I added some data.

Comment: Sure @RonakShah.

Comment: wow. That was easy. Thanks @RonakShah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `round` to format decimal places in "Period" objects.

```
head(round(time, 2))
#[1] "2d 7H 1M 5.32S"   "1d 9H 20M 37.49S" "7H 39M 37.95S" "2d 5H 0M 41.01S" 
#    "1d 8H 32M 2.8S"   "6H 36M 25.19S"
```